# Make a python line of code into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, centos7

When I type this into the terminal I get the output right away. I would like to make this into a variable and use it on my code

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("MyPassword", "$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$")'
```

I have tried something like this

```
 Password = python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("MyPassword", "$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$")'
```

Comment: Variable for what? What kind of code is "your code"?

Comment: do you want to assign this value to a variable in a bash script? or python ?

Comment: @Murali yes I'm using the code inside ,shell file. The return value from `python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("MyPassword", "$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$")'` should be in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* by 'variable' you mean a variable in Python code, just put your code into a Python script file, for example `mycrypt.py`.

```
import crypt

mypassword = crypt.crypt("MyPassword", "$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$")
```

The variable `mypassword` can then be used later in this Python script.

**Edit:** In bash assign the result of the python execution to a variable

```
$ password=$(python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("MyPassword", "$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$")')
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm running the code on bash .sh script.

Comment: When using `$password = $(python -c 'import crypt; crypt.crypt("MyPassword", "$6$LsCK1WmouFiO9AT/$")')` I get an error `=: command not found`

Comment: There must not be a blank in front or after the `=`. That's how variable assignment in bash works.

Comment: It Works! Thank you so much for you assistance and guidance. I've learn't something great today.

Comment: Glad I could help. Have fun.